# Integrity Checks are failing

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, dbcc

Needs some help understanding how a restore process works when you have a hard disk failure and a server shutdown.

We run MSSQL2005 server.  We take a full backup every night and logs every hour.

We had a disk failure on a Raid 5 storage drive, (2) hours before a backup.  The db came back on line, after a server shutdown, but there are no transaction logs for 8 hours after the failure.

When I run DBCC CHECKDB, the long report lists:

Here are the last three entries in the CHECKDB file.  There was a long list of Extent entries.

```
Extent (1:4591784) in database ID 9 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated it.
CHECKDB found 7288 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
CHECKDB found 7288 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB".
```

The last known good backup was 2 days ago.  I tried to run a restore rather than repair_allow_data_loss, but each time I try a restore and run an Integrity Check on the db it fails for the same reason and the DBCC CHECKDB file lists the same issues.

How can I get beyond this issue?  If I was to run the repair_allow_data_loss, how much data could I be losing?  Would the loss include years of past data or just data since the time of failure?

Answer (score 0):

Take backup of current database with continue after error.

BACKUP DATABASE db_name to disk='Location' with continue_after_error

Now restore this backup ON Different server. After this, run DBCC CHECKDB with repair_allow_data_loss

Now you can see how much data "DBCC CHECKDB with repair_allow_data_loss"  has deleted to recover your database.

Please take reference from Online Document before doing this.